# Graphite and statsd - how to change graphe metric to 1 min

Tags: graphite, statsd, grafana

I have installed statsd with Graphite.

I wrote a sample that increases a counter (please see below).

I was expecting to see a line on 60 because I am increasing a counter every sec, however the line that I get is somewhat random, the range is between 14-29. below you can see a screenshot of the graph.

How can I change the Graph to show 60 per 1 min ?

contents of /etc/statsd/localConfig.js

```
{
  graphitePort: 2003
, graphiteHost: "localhost"
, port: 8125
, flushInterval: 60000
, graphite: {
    legacyNamespace: false
  }
}
```

contents of storage-schemas.conf

```
[statsd]
pattern = ^stats\.
retentions = 60s:90d

[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 60s:14d
```

contents of storage-aggregation.conf

```
[min]
pattern = \.min$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = min

[max]
pattern = \.max$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = max

[count]
pattern = \.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[lower]
pattern = \.lower(_\d+)?$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = min

[upper]
pattern = \.upper(_\d+)?$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = max

[sum]
pattern = \.sum$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[gauges]
pattern = ^.*\.gauges\..*
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = last

[default_average]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor = 0.5
aggregationMethod = average
```

statsd send 60 metrics to graphite every minute.

```
require 'statsd-ruby'

$statsd = Statsd.new '23.23.82.106', 8125

loop do 
    $statsd.increment 'xxx'
    puts "sent at #{Time.now.strftime "%H:%M:%S"}"
    sleep 1
end
```

The Graph looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [statsd-graphite](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/graphite.md) docs:

> ensure your flush interval is at least as long as the
>   highest-resolution retention

Otherwise Graphite will only record the last seen value. The default flush interval for statsd is 10 seconds, however in

```
[statsd]
pattern = ^stats\.
retentions = 60s:90d
```

You are setting the highest-resolution retention to 60 seconds. So your statsd flush interval is shorter than your Graphite highest- resolution retention.

To fix it simply use:

```
[statsd]
pattern = ^stats\.
retentions = 10s:60s:90d
```

You might have to resize your `wsp` files to match the new resolution configuration.

See [this blog post](https://kevinmccarthy.org/2013/07/18/10-things-i-learned-deploying-graphite/) (point 4) for a slightly longer explanation of the observed effect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the line is still random, I also tried to remove the old wsp files.
You mentioned that The default flush interval for statsd is 10 seconds, but did you saw that I changed statsd's config to "flushInterval: 60000" to ensure statsd and graphite are in sync and because of that I set the retentions = 60s:90d to make statsd send metrics to graphite every minute.